# jQuery Append element from iframe to it's body parent window. 

Tags: jquery, iframe, append

I have 
`elm.appendTo('#wrap');`

where `elm` is a jquery object of the clicked image inside iframe. I want to append that image to a `<div id="wrap">` where `#wrap` is a div in the body of the page outside iframe. So basically when i double click on an image inside iframe, i want that image to append to `<body>` outside iframe. Both body and iframe link are on the same domain.

Comment: Does it not work or something? You've just described a working system to me, by the sounds of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Provided that the frame and its parent are at the same domain. See [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

---

Execute either of the following lines from **within** the iframe (`parent` can be replaced by `top`, if the parent document is in the top window):

```
//If the parent document doesn't have JQuery:
elm.appendTo(parent.document.getElementById("wrap"));

//Only if JQuery is included at the parent
elm.appendTo(parent.$("#wrap"));
parent.$("#wrap").append(elm);
```

---

If you want to grab the element inside the frame, from the context of the **parent**, use either of the following:

Assume `#elm` to be the ID of your image.

```
// If JQuery is defined at the frame AND the parent (current document)
$("#wrap").append(frames[0].$("#elm"));
frames[0].$("#elm").appendTo($("#wrap"));
```

`frames[0]` refers to the first frame within the current document. If you've set a `name` attribute on your frame, you can also use `frames.frame_name`, or `frames["frame_name"]`.

---

**Final example**: Adding a `click` event listener to the `elm` JQuery (image) object:

```
elm.click(function(){
    parent.$("#wrap").append(this);
})
```

Comment: I want to append to #wrap inside body and not to body

Comment: Appending an object to an element does not overwrite the contents of the container. Simply adjust the selector (as shown in the answer) to fit your wishes.

Comment: The question is clear. I have <body><div id="wrap"><iframe></body> I want to append image from iframe to #wrap

Comment: You defined `elm` to be the JQuery object of the `<img>` element. The code I've shown in my answer should be called from within the frame. `parent.$("body")` refers to the parent `<body>` element.

Comment: I'm actually calling the append code from outside iframe. Is that possible

Comment: So basically i have the append js code in body and i'm listening to clicks inside iframe then append the clicked image to body.

Comment: Thanks Rob, This was very helpful. With a little modifications from my end, i got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try going at it from the other way: from the parent window, find the element you want to append to and then use `.append()` and select the element in the iframe.  For example:

```
$("#wrap").append($("iframe #myElement"));
```

Comment: `$("#wrap").append($("iframe #myElement"));`

Comment: how can i use `elm` which is a jQuery obeject instead of #myElement as you suggested. elm is a jQuery object of the image, `$('<img src=...>')`

Comment: Just replace the selector in `.append()` with it: `$("#wrap").append(elm);`

Comment: This code makes no sense. `$("iframe #myElement")` selects an element identified by `#myElement` within the `iframe` tag. The selectors don't search for elements within the frame.

Comment: This code makes perfect sense. I'm approaching the problem from the parent frame.  In the parent frame, find the element you want to append to ( `$("#wrap)` ) then append the content that is inside your iframe ( `.append()` ).  I'm just approaching the problem from a different angle (top down instead of bottom up).

Comment: sorry jtfairbank i can't make sense of your last comment. How is that going to append an image from iframe to outside iframe

Comment: It is based on the js code being outside of the iframe.  So instead of having js inside the iframe get the image and move it outside the iframe, it uses js outside the iframe to grab the image inside the iframe and move it out of the iframe.  Sorry if its not helpful.

Comment: Yup.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.